# Setup email to recieve mails from outlook to sharepoint

Tags: 2007, calendar, incoming-email, smtp

We need to send emails through outlook to create events in SharePoint Calendars. For this we have installed SMTP services on our Server ( 2003). **The SMTP server is shown stopped in IIS.
Do we need to start it so that Calendar can receive mails?**

Also, in the central admin we have configured email settings with domain say 'abc.com'. **We have created a new mail id testCalendar@abc.com for this Calendar. Do we need to configure/add this in SMTP server?**

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you correctly configured Incoming Email in SharePoint. On one of your WFE you need to configure SMTP. POP3 is not needed as the WFE serves as relay mainly. See here for a guide http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2010/08/16/configuring-incoming-email-for-sharepoint-2010-foundations.aspx

Than you need to enable calendars to receive events by email, see here http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/view-and-update-a-sharepoint-calendar-HA010081987.aspx

See here for more details too http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint_blank/archive/2008/09/05/adding-an-event-to-a-sharepoint-calendar-via-email.aspx